Is x-amz-server-side-encryption still required to to prevent uploads of unencrypted objects to Amazon S3
I want to confirm my understanding that with the announcement of Amazon S3 now automatically encrypts all new objects renders the procedure described in How to Prevent Uploads of Unencrypted Objects to Amazon S3 unnecessary? The old procedure required x-amz-server-side-encryption header.
The SSE-S3 encryption is applied by default starting January 5, 2023
The FAQ from the new announcement:

Is default encryption enabled on my existing buckets that don't have default encryption configured?
Yes. Amazon S3 now configures default encryption on all existing unencrypted buckets to apply server-side encryption with S3 managed keys (SSE-S3) as the base level of encryption for new objects uploaded to these buckets.
Can I disable encryption for the new objects being written to my bucket?
No. SSE-S3 is the new base level of encryption that's applied to all the new objects being uploaded to your bucket. You can no longer disable encryption for new object uploads.


If your requirement is simply SSE-S3 then I think it's now unnecessary but not if your requirement is SSE-KMS.

My question is about any encryption, SSE-S3 is fine
